# do we have a TCL script to generate XML file?

Tags: xml, tcl, itcl

> i made a script using tcldom:

```
package require utils
package require testrunscheduler
package require tdom
tla::TSConfig::init -schedulerContext "Reporting" -environment production
tla::TSDBFactory::getConnection db
set testCaseList [$db doSQL "SELECT root_name,suite_name,case_name FROM ics where test_type = 'tce' limit 1"]
set item [join $testCaseList ""]

set doc [dom createDocument testCases]
set root [$doc documentElement]
set subnode [$doc createElement testCase]
$root appendChild $subnode

foreach item $item {
set node [$doc createElement root]
$node appendChild [$doc createTextNode $item]
$subnode appendChild $node
}
```

> Output i get is :

```
<testCases>
    <testCase>
        <root>SPB</root>
        <root>subscriberServices</root>
        <root>jmsServices</root>
    </testCase>
</testCases>
```

> but i want output to be like :

```
<testCases>
    <testCase>
        <root>SPB</root>
        <suite>subscriberServices</suite>
        <case>jmsServices</case>
    </testCase>
</testCases>
```

> i used foreach for this, but it makes only for root, i am missing probably, this structure would iterate itself and grow as on the users input from sql query.

```
<testCases>
    <testCase>
        <root>demoRoot</root>
        <suite>demoSuite</suite>
        <case>demoCase</case>
        <testCase>test_demo001</testCase>
    </testCase>
    <testCase>
        <root>demoRoot</root>
        <suite>demoSuite</suite>
        <case>demoCase</case>
        <testCase>test_demo002</testCase>
    </testCase>
</testCases>
```

Please help me to get this kind of output, its very tedious to get this putput which is repetative but with one structure.

Comment: Take a look at the tdom package, which is excellent for this kind of tasks. There is a tutorial on the wiki, search for tdom.

Comment: Which wiki page were you looking at?

Comment: Tdom works the other way, I.e XML to raw or text conversion is what I understood , there is another package called xmlgen but that package is not installed and not allowed to install in my testing environment @Peter

Comment: @vinay: tdom works both ways, actually. I use it both to parse HTML/XML and to build it.

Comment: @Peter Lewerin: is there any example script which could help me get the output as you said using tdom?

Answer (score 2):

```
package require tdom

set data {
    {demoRoot1 demoSuite1 demoCase1}
    {demoRoot2 demoSuite2 demoCase2}
}

set doc [dom createDocument testCases]
set root [$doc documentElement]

dom createNodeCmd elementNode testCase
dom createNodeCmd elementNode root
dom createNodeCmd elementNode suite
dom createNodeCmd elementNode case
dom createNodeCmd textNode t

foreach line $data {
    lassign $line _root suite case
    # or (if you don't have lassign) foreach {_root suite case} $line break

    $root appendFromScript {
        testCase {
            root {t $_root}
            suite {t $suite}
            case {t $case}
            testCase {t [format {test_demo%03d} [incr num]]}
        }
    }
}

$doc asXML
```

Output:

```
<testCases>
    <testCase>
        <root>demoRoot1</root>
        <suite>demoSuite1</suite>
        <case>demoCase1</case>
        <testCase>test_demo001</testCase>
    </testCase>
    <testCase>
        <root>demoRoot2</root>
        <suite>demoSuite2</suite>
        <case>demoCase2</case>
        <testCase>test_demo002</testCase>
    </testCase>
</testCases>
```

See the tutorial on the wiki for more examples.

Documentation:
[break](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/break.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[tdom (package)](http://tdom.github.io)

Comment: i have reformatted the question, please help me get the output as mentioned above

Comment: @vinay: like this?

Comment: yeah that helps , thanks a lot.. i had to modifiy a bit according to my requirement to create test_demo00#

Comment: hey Peter can you help this done? i have another query but related to this problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216742/is-that-possible-to-create-a-list-of-list-in-tcl

@Peter Lewerin